# Is it possible to download the contents of a public Lambda layer from AWS given the ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I want to download the public arn for a more compact version of spacy from this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/keithrozario/Klayers/blob/master/deployments/python3.7/arns/us-west-2.csv%3E).

```
"arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:113088814899:layer:Klayers-python37-spacy:27"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get it from a Arn using the [get-layer-version-by-arn function](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/get-layer-version-by-arn.html) in the CLI.

You can run the below command to get the source of the Lambda layer you requested.

```
aws lambda get-layer-version-by-arn \
    --arn "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:113088814899:layer:Klayers-python37-spacy:27"
```

An example of the response you will receive is below

```
{
    "LayerVersionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:layer:AWSLambda-Python37-SciPy1x:2",
    "Description": "AWS Lambda SciPy layer for Python 3.7 (scipy-1.1.0, numpy-1.15.4) https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v1.1.0 https://github.com/numpy/numpy/releases/tag/v1.15.4",
    "CreatedDate": "2018-11-12T10:09:38.398+0000",
    "LayerArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:layer:AWSLambda-Python37-SciPy1x",
    "Content": {
        "CodeSize": 41784542,
        "CodeSha256": "GGmv8ocUw4cly0T8HL0Vx/f5V4RmSCGNjDIslY4VskM=",
        "Location": "https://awslambda-us-west-2-layers.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/snapshots/123456789012/..."
    },
    "Version": 2,
    "CompatibleRuntimes": [
        "python3.7"
    ],
    "LicenseInfo": "SciPy: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/LICENSE.txt, NumPy: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/LICENSE.txt"
}
```

Once you run this you will get a response returned with a key of `"Content"`, containing a subkey of `"Location"` which references the S3 path to download the layer contents.

You can download from this path, you will then need to [configure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) this as a Lambda layer again after removing any dependencies.

Please ensure in this process that you only remove unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: If I want to use pandas in the same layer as spacy, would I be able to add that to the downloaded layer?

Comment: Yes, you can either unzip add pandas, rezip and then upload as your own layer or alternatively use his layer and then create a secondary layer above that includes only pandas :)

Comment: ok got it. so if i want to use pandas and spacy i don't even need them in the same layer. i just need the correct versions of each. thx dude.

Comment: Exactly, layers can work together. Glad I could help you :)

Comment: can I just drag and drop a package into the folder with spacy? really struggling to get pandas to work in lambda

Comment: I guess the two " are by mistake

Comment: You can add the ` --query Content.Location --output text` flags to get just the URL.